# natural transformation between set-theoretic functions

Tags: category-theory

By definition, a natural transformation $\alpha:F\rightarrow G$, with $F,G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ must associate with every object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$ an arrow $\alpha_c:Fc\rightarrow Gc$ . But if $F$ and $G$ are set-theoretic functions while $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are sets treated as discrete categories, it seems that for each $c\in \mathcal{C}$, $\alpha_c$ must be unique (since it must send $Fc$ to $Gc$, while both are discrete objects in $\mathcal{D}$). Am I missing something, or are natural transformations between set-theoretic functions necessarily unique?

Comment: The only arrows in a discrete category are identities, so natural transformations between functors $F, G : DX\to DY$ are unique because there's only one possible natural transformation, namely the identity natural transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see. I forgot the crucial fact that $\alpha_c$ must be a morphism in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins: Why do you post a complete answer as a comment? From outside this question is still unanswered.